# Wordpress custom login and register page problem?

Tags: page-template, homepage

I have created custom pages login page and register page in wordpress. My login page has to come when i visit the site. How do i make login page as the first page on the site. And how do i remove register and login pages from the tab structure.

Comment: do you want to restrict your site and want it to be viewed by  registered user only??

Comment: Yes actually i am converting my wordpress site into a social networking blogging site with use of budy press.

Comment: what do u mean by "how do i remove register and login pages from the tab structure" could you explain it some more

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the Log In page your landing page is to go to Dashboard > Settings > Reading and find:

Front Page displays  ( ) Your latest posts
                     (x) A static page

Select your "home page" (which will be the Log In page) and your blog page appropriately in the drop down menus.

Regarding buddypress tab/menu structure...  I'm not that familiar with that.  I feel like there's some code you can just add to your child theme's functions.php to remove that sort of feature but I'm unsure what.

Answer (score 0):

to restrict unregistered users use the [Registered Users Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/registered-users-only/) plugin by Viper007Bond or [Members Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-only/) plugin by hami.